# SQL Server 2008: Diff table data on different servers with exact schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-tools

I'm trying to find a good open source tool that simply compares data in a database on one server to a table (of the same schema) on another server.  Then I want to generate INSERT statements for the rows that are different, for either the source or destination/target table.

I've tried downloading several tools, and I can't get any of them to work because they all had bugs.  I can be more specific with the errors I received if you need me to be.

I've tried:

```
TableDiffGui.zip
SqlDiffFramework setup 1.0.3.0.exe
SqlTableCompare.zip
DaBCoS.0.3.2163.zip
```

If there is a manual way to do this, please let me know.  My last resort will be to simply write a program that does it.

Comment: Do you really want to insert all of the rows that are different? Even if the key is the same and/or all of the columns are the same except one? Seems like what you might be looking for is MERGE if you're trying to keep two tables in sync (without using replication / mirroring / etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is creating a linked server on one of those an option?  If so you could probably do this using something similar to the following query (untested):

```
INSERT INTO Server1.db1.dbo.Table1
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table2
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Server1.db1.dbo.Table1
```

If not, then maybe take a look at [SQL Server replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Nice Query +! could also take a look at [RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) for that however it's certainly not free.

Comment: I'm checking with our DBAs if I can get permissions to add linked servers.  Good thought of doing a federated query.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you found that TableDiffGui has bugs. Have you tried using [TableDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx) directly? You might not run into the same problems.

Comment: no, I have not tried that yet.